# Can Not Load Static Files in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to add an image to a very basic html template. I am able to render the html file, but unfortunately the image will not display.

Here is my error:

```
Not Found: /exapp/pic.jpg
[21/Apr/2018 18:43:49] "GET /exapp/pic.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2145
```

I noticed that django was looking for the file with a path of /exapp/pic.jpg, so I created a folder in my static directory called exapp, and put the image in there. Still no image :(

the file structure is as follows:

```
    ─ db.sqlite3
├── exapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── exapp
│   │       └── pic.jpg
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── mysite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

Here is the HTML file in question:

```
    <html>
    <head> 
        <title> Hello world</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Look it worked 
    {% load static %}
    <img src="pic.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="420">
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the settings file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'tie19%e+ri*g3#54b)axh&!8rentwx)xnsjbk&kx09(10le%7a'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'exapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Here is my views and URL files together:

```
 ---------url.py in mysite folder------------
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('exapp/',include('exapp.urls')),
    ]
    -----------urls.py in exapp folder--------------
    from django.urls import path


    from . import views 

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
    ]

 ----------Views in exapp folder--------------------------
    from django.shortcuts import render

    # Create your views here.
    from django.http import HttpResponse


    def index(request):
        return render(request,'index.html')
```

So as a rundown, the HTML template does render to the page. But I for some reason can not figure out how to get the image linked in the html code to display to the screen. Everything seems to be in the correct place. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to change your image source.

This is what you have:

```
<img src="pic.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="420">
```

Try this:

```
<img src="{% static "exapp/pic.jpg" %}" alt="Smiley face" height="200" width="420">
```

This worked for me!

Good luck!